Why does Dexie give me "The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found"?
I have the following very basic Dexie app:
$(document).ready(function(){                                                                                               
    let demo = {                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
        init: function () {                                                                                                 
            that = this;                                                                                                    
            that.putQunitsIntoDatabase();             
        },                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                            
        getBlockQunitAndCreateRandomBlock: function() {                                                                     
              that.db.transaction('r', 'qunits', async () => {                                                              
                that.allValidQunits = await that.db.qunits.where('step').belowOrEqual(2);                                   
              }).then(() => {                                                                                               
                console.log('that.allValidQunits as array:');                                                               
                console.log(that.allValidQunits.toArray());                                                                 
              });                                                                                                           
        },                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                            
        setupQunits: function() {                                                                                           
            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 1,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'purchase'                                                                                     
            });                                                                                                             
            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 2,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'inventory'                                                                                    
            });                                                                                                             
            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 3,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'log'                                                                                          
            });                                                                                                             
        },  
                                                                                                             
        putQunitsIntoDatabase: function() {                                                                                 
            var dbName = 'myProject';                                                                                       
            that.db = new Dexie(dbName);                                                                                    
            that.db.version(1).stores({                                                                                     
              qunits: 'id++,step,function'                                                                                  
            });                                                                                                             
            that.db.open().catch(function (e) {                                                                             
              console.error("Open failed.");                                                                                
              console.log(e);                                                                                               
            })                                                                                                              
            that.db.transaction('rw', 'qunits', function () {                                                               
            $(that.qunits).each(function(i,v){                                                                              
              that.db.qunits.add({                                                                                      
                level: v['step'],                                                                                       
                functionName: v['function']                                                                             
              });                                                                                                       
            });                                                                                                         
            })                                                                                                          
            .then(function(){                                                                                           
              that.getBlockQunitAndCreateRandomBlock();                                                                 
            })                                                                                                          
            .catch (function (e) {                                                                                      
              console.error('transaction failed.');                                                                     
              console.error(e);                                                                                         
            });                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                        
    demo.init();                                                                                                        
}); 

... and when I run it, my console shows an object that includes this key/value pair:

_value: Object { _e: Error, name: "NotFoundError", message: "The operation failed because the requested database object could not be
found. For example, an object store did not exist but was being
opened.", … }

The last post I saw about this had an answer suggesting that this was a Firefox bug, but that was 6 years ago, and I suspect that I'm just doing something wrong, rather than hitting an antique Firefox bug. Are there any obvious mistakes I'm making here? And if so, what do I change to get my two selected array members into the output?

Edit #1
I have verified that everything up through console.log(that.allValidQunits.toArray()); runs. In other words, this NotFoundError is coming from whatever is returned by my where query, not from some earlier part of the program.
Edit #2
It's worth noting that I am not primarily a JavaScript developer. While my main interest is in getting my Dexie query to behave, I'm happy to hear of ancillary things I can improve in my JS in general.
Edit #3
This issue is on Firefox 125.0 (64-bit). Chrome gives me a Promise object with a _value being an array of length zero, which is still not ideally what I'm looking for but will maybe provide a clue. I'm pulling in dexie via the following <script> tag at the top of my page:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@2.0.4/dist/dexie.js"></script>


Looks like this issue is supposed to have been fixed in Firebase JS SDK 4.13, about 6 years ago as you mentioned. Can you confirm you're using a version at or higher than that?

@l3l_aze -- thanks for the comment. I've added more information in a third edit on the question.

Sorry for the stupidity, lol - Firebase has nothing to do with Dexie and probably little to no relevance to this issue (though the tests provided in the above issue do fail & pass as specified).  It's possible this is a regression in Firefox, but that is a 6 year old version of Dexie, so it'd be worth trying to update it as the current release is 4.0.7. Because it's +2 major versions (4 v 2) there may be some breaking changes that'd need to be fixed. If the error continues after an upgrade though, then it is likely a regression that'd need fixed.

Thanks, @l3l_aze. Updating to 4.0.7 seems to have fixed the problem I posted about. Now I just need to change my script so it's not creating an empty array, but I won't move the goalposts on you: If you write this up as an answer, I'll go ahead and award you the bounty, since you had the answer first.

That's okay, it was something simple you would've stumbled on, but easier to consider from the outside.

check this , some explanation is inside comments
ofcourse  every time you run this it will add 3 record on qunits
you need to check if it is initialized or move all puts out of init
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@2.0.4/dist/dexie.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){                                                                                               
    let demo = {                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
        init: function () {                                                                                                 
            that = this;  
            that.setupQunits();                                                                                                  
            that.putQunitsIntoDatabase();             
        },                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                            
        getBlockQunitAndCreateRandomBlock: function() {                                                                     
              that.db.transaction('r', 'qunits', async () => {                                                              
                return that.db.qunits.where('step').belowOrEqual(2).toArray();

              }).then((res) => {   
                that.allValidQunits=res;                                                                                          
                console.log('that.allValidQunits as array:');                                                               
                console.log(that.allValidQunits);                                                                 
              });                                                                                                           
        },                                                                                                                  
        //you nerver call this in your original code
        //i put the call inside demo.init                                                                                                               
        setupQunits: function() {
            
            //that.qunits were never initialized to array
            if(!(that?.qunits))that.qunits=[];

            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 1,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'purchase'                                                                                     
            });                                                                                                             
            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 2,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'inventory'                                                                                    
            });                                                                                                             
            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 3,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'log'                                                                                          
            });                                                                                                             
        },  
                                                                                                             
        putQunitsIntoDatabase: function() {                                                                                 
            var dbName = 'myProject';                                                                                       
            that.db = new Dexie(dbName);                                                                                    
            that.db.version(1).stores({                                                                                     
              qunits: 'id++,step,function'                                                                                  
            });                                                                                                             
            that.db.open().catch(function (e) {                                                                             
              console.error("Open failed.");                                                                                
              console.log(e);                                                                                               
            })                                                                                                              
            that.db.transaction('rw', 'qunits', function () {                                                               
                $(that.qunits).each(function(i,v){     
                    // this is the main reason of your fail
                    //qunits: 'id++,step,function'  <= qunits expect step,function not level,functionName
                    /*
                    that.db.qunits.add({                                                                                      
                        level: v['step'],                                                                                       
                        functionName: v['function']                                                                             
                    });    
                    */                                                                       ;
                    that.db.qunits.add({                                                                                      
                        'step': v['step'],                                                                                       
                        'functionName': v['function']                                                                             
                    });                                                                                                       
                });                                                                                                         
            })                                                                                                                                                                                            
            .then(function(){                                                                                           
              that.getBlockQunitAndCreateRandomBlock();                                                                 
            })                                                                                                          
            .catch (function (e) {                                                                                      
              console.error('transaction failed.');                                                                     
              console.error(e);                                                                                         
            });                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                        
    demo.init();                                                                                                        
}); 
</script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@2.0.4/dist/dexie.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){                                                                                               
    let demo = {                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
        init: function () {                                                                                                 
            that = this;  
            that.setupQunits();                                                                                                  
            that.putQunitsIntoDatabase();             
        },                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                            
        getBlockQunitAndCreateRandomBlock: function() {                                                                     
              that.db.transaction('r', 'qunits', async () => {                                                              
                return that.db.qunits.where('step').belowOrEqual(2).toArray();

              }).then((res) => {   
                that.allValidQunits=res;                                                                                          
                console.log('that.allValidQunits as array:');                                                               
                console.log(that.allValidQunits);                                                                 
              });                                                                                                           
        },                                                                                                                  
        //you nerver call this in your original code
        //i put the call inside demo.init                                                                                                               
        setupQunits: function() {
            
            //that.qunits were never initialized to array
            if(!(that?.qunits))that.qunits=[];

            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 1,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'purchase'                                                                                     
            });                                                                                                             
            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 2,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'inventory'                                                                                    
            });                                                                                                             
            that.qunits.push({                                                                                              
                'step' : 3,                                                                                                 
                'function' : 'log'                                                                                          
            });                                                                                                             
        },  
                                                                                                             
        putQunitsIntoDatabase: function() {                                                                                 
            var dbName = 'myProject';                                                                                       
            that.db = new Dexie(dbName);                                                                                    
            that.db.version(1).stores({                                                                                     
              qunits: 'id++,step,function'                                                                                  
            });                                                                                                             
            that.db.open().catch(function (e) {                                                                             
              console.error("Open failed.");                                                                                
              console.log(e);                                                                                               
            })                                                                                                              
            that.db.transaction('rw', 'qunits', function () {                                                               
                $(that.qunits).each(function(i,v){     
                    // this is the main reason of your fail
                    //qunits: 'id++,step,function'  <= qunits expect step,function not level,functionName
                    /*
                    that.db.qunits.add({                                                                                      
                        level: v['step'],                                                                                       
                        functionName: v['function']                                                                             
                    });    
                    */                                                                       ;
                    that.db.qunits.add({                                                                                      
                        'step': v['step'],                                                                                       
                        'functionName': v['function']                                                                             
                    });                                                                                                       
                });                                                                                                         
            })                                                                                                                                                                                            
            .then(function(){                                                                                           
              that.getBlockQunitAndCreateRandomBlock();                                                                 
            })                                                                                                          
            .catch (function (e) {                                                                                      
              console.error('transaction failed.');                                                                     
              console.error(e);                                                                                         
            });                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                        
    demo.init();                                                                                                        
}); 
</script>

i think it works
